# Color-filled box in text area with size corresponding to font size

Tags: color, boxes

Is it possible to construct a small, color-filled box in text among ordinary text? The size of the box should correspond to the font size.

I need it because I need to construct a legend for some graphics that I have constructed elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\fontcharht` it's easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\legendbox}[1]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{\fontcharht\font`X}{\fontcharht\font`X}}%
}

\begin{document}
\legendbox{blue} This is some text \legendbox{red}

\Large\legendbox{blue} This is some text \legendbox{olive}

\Huge\legendbox{blue!60} This is some text \legendbox{green!20}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\mybox}[1][red]{\scalerel*{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}}{d}}
\begin{document}
  \mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]

  \Large\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]

  \Huge\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `scalerel` also this works since `ex` units are used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\mybox}[1][red]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{1.5ex}{1.5ex}}}
\begin{document}
  \mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]

  \Large\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]

  \Huge\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you have to set `1.5ex` as you wish once.

Comment: Perhaps a multi-scale demo would be useful, as in `\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]\Large\mybox[blue] This is some text \mybox{} Again \mybox[olive]`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks and added :-)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a different way that does not apply scalerel? For some reason, my compiler is not able to find scalerel.sty despite it being in the "\texmf-dist\tex\latex" folder.

Comment: @Marcus Please see the update.